# Option Select Issue while loading from Database

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I am loading the option select from database. It loads the element properly. But for the rows with double character i am facing the error

```
<select>
<option value="Printed">Printed</option>
<option value="Yarn" dyed="">Yarn Dyed</option>
</select>
```

Which is expected as

```
<option value="Yarn Dyed">Yarn Dyed</option>
```

This is what the error happens,

Here i have included the code for reference

```
{{ Form::select('DupPackaging[0]', $packaging, '', array('class' => 'choiceSelect empty my_prs_sele', 'id' => 'DupPackaging1' )); }}
```

This is my Controller

```
$tbl4 = DB::table('packaging')->where('Status', '=', 1)->orderBy('PackagName', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Could you provide the controller which sends $packaging to the view?

Comment: @cas bloem : i have update my question

Comment: Can you provide the $packaging ?

Comment: Also, the `select` should have the class and id. Did you remove them?